# is AES encryption/decryption deterministic and machine agnostic?

Tags: aes

If the key and seed remain unchanged, will the encryption/decryption always yield the same results, and do so regardless of the machine on which the algorithm implementation is executing? A value encrypted on a desktop can be decrypted on a server or on another desktop (as long as the key and seed are known)?  Changes in server security certificates, etc are irrelevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the AES algorithm is standardized and the machine used has no influence on the result of the encryption. Knowing the seed, the key and the chaining-mode used any computer can decrypt an encrypted message.

Regarding your second question certificates are used with asymmetric encryption (algorithms like e.g. RSA) and are therefore not relevant to AES which is a symmetric algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I can accept your answer in 2 minutes :-)